# How to use text-input to go to anchor?

Tags: jquery, input, textbox, anchor

I want to use jQuery to go to an anchor with the use of a textbox, for example, I want to use this form:

```
<form id="gotoanchorform">
    <input id="gotoanchorinput" type="text" />
    <input type="submit" value="Go to anchor" />
</form>
```

In this form I would type the name of the anchor and when I click the "Go to anchor" button or press the enter key I want the page to scroll down to that anchor:

```
<a name="targetAnchor" id="targetAnchor">Target</a>
```

How would get this to work with jQuery?

Comment: I would suggest googling "jquery scrollto". Other than it's mostly just appending .val()s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    var anchor = $("#gotoanchorinput").val();
    var position = $("#"+anchor).offset();
    window.scrollTo(position.left, position.top);
```

This piece of code make your page scroll to the anchor written in `#gotoanchorinput`.

Answer (score 0):

Simply do:

```
var url = $('#gotoanchorinput').val();    
$(location).attr('href',url);
```

Comment: Then he would also have to simulate a click on the anchor.

Answer (score 0):

try something like this:

```
$(function() {
    $('form#gotoanchorform').submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var desired = $('#gotoanchorinput').val();

        window.location.href = window.location.href + '#' + desired;

        // or

        $('html, body').animate({'scrollTop', $('a[name*="' + desired +'"').offset().top + 'px'}, 900);


        return false;
    });
});
```

so if you would type "foo" and click submit, the page would scroll to an  which name attribute contains "foo"

Answer (score 0):

HTML part:

```
<form id="myForm" data-anchor="#myAnchor">
    <input type="text" />
    <input type="submit" value="Go to anchor" />
</form>
```

*NB: data-x attribute is valid HTML.*

JS part:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#myForm').submit(function(e){

        $(location).attr('href', $(this).attr('data-anchor'));

        return false;
    });
});
```