# ASP.NET MVC C# - Pass dynamic parameter using URL ACTION

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

How can I pass the value of my textbox "R_endDate" from my VIEW to my controller ExportToExcel function using Url.Action ?

On my View: Index.cshtml

I have this textbox with value of date.

```
<div class="uk-form-row">
    <label class="uk-form-label" for="R_endDate">Ending Date:</label>
    <div class="uk-form-controls">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.R_endDate, new { @class = "uk-form-small uk-text-left required", @maxlength = 12, @data_uk_datepicker = "{format: 'MM/DD/YYYY'}" })

    </div>
</div>
```

I have this anchor tag with url action.

```
<a href="@Url.Action("ExportToExcel")" class="uk-button uk-button-small uk-text-center uk-text-small ">Export</a>
```

On my Controller: MISReportController.cs

```
 public FileContentResult ExportToExcel()
    {
    byte[] filecontent = ExcelExportHelper.ExportExcel(list, "Technology", true, strAddtional);
    return File(filecontent, ExcelExportHelper.ExcelContentType, strTitle);

    }
```

[my scripts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xbSVY.png)

[error1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yYMbX.png)

Comment: You can better handle anchor click in JavaScript or modify anchor href in javscript code, for example https://stackoverflow.com/a/12250499/713789

Comment: You cant - `@Url.Action()` is razor code. It is paersed on the server before the view is sent to the browser. Use a form (with `FormMethod.Get` and post the form to you method), or use javascript to build the url

Answer (score 3):

You can easily handle this using javascript/jquery.

UI:

```
<a id="aExportToExcel" href="#" class="uk-button uk-button-small uk-text-center uk-text-small ">Export</a>
```

Script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#aExportToExcel").click(function () {
        var param = $("input[name='R_endDate']").val();
        var _url = '@Url.Action("ExportToExcel", "MISReportController", new { param = "XXX" })'; // Param is the example parameter name. Change as needed.
        _url = _url.replace("XXX", param); // _url will contain your url string so you can just play with it as needed for your requirement.

        window.open(_url, "_blank");
    });
});

</script>
```

Comment: ajax call is better than this one?

Comment: public FileContentResult ExportToExcel(string param), when I check the param value it is null. Any idea sir?

Comment: @MohanSrinivas why is it better? @Jadina check the name of your textbox, I simply assumed it was `R_endDate`. Change if the razor-generated name is different.

Comment: Just pass the model value as a data while click the link and get the result right?

Comment: @MohanSrinivas based on my experience with file downloading using ajax, it will not be downloaded as is because your success callback will have to handle blob data. But if you prefer to persue that approach then you may. I am not qualified to decide which is better.

Comment: -the name of my textbox is R_endDate base on the above code. i.e. "@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.R_endDate..."
I'm using alert too, but it is not alerting the param.
 $("#aExportToExcel").onclick(function () {
 var param = $("input[name='R_endDate']").val();
 alert(param); <-- not alerting

Comment: @Jadina try changing the a href to "#" to prevent the default behavior of anchor elements. Sorry I forgot to write it that way.

Comment: @JohnEphraimTugado, when i changed it, it is not clickable anymore... it is not going to my controller function when debugging.

Comment: @Jadina change `onclick` to `click`. I got mixed up with jquery and basic javascript. No excuse.

Comment: @JohnEphraimTugado still the same sir...  , I've added alert below document.ready function but it is not alerting "$(document).ready(function () { alert('test');", Is there a problem with the script?

Comment: @Jadina where are you placing your scripts? In MVC I believe you should place it inside `@section scripts {}`. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23327673/6138713) for more info.

Comment: yes sir, i included that on my section scripts see my attached image on my post... here's the link [link]https://i.stack.imgur.com/xbSVY.png

Comment: @Jadina you need `jquery` for this. Is it included in your `_Layout.cshtml`? You can try pressing `F12` in your browser and on the console tab see if there are any errors which you have to address. Do this before refreshing the page.

Comment: Sir, please check the error now, here's the link...  Yes, it's passing the parameter but it is not going to my function when debugging... https://i.stack.imgur.com/yYMbX.png

Comment: @Jadina your razor code `@Url.Action` did not work. You must make sure to place it on the cshtml page so that the razor syntax could be recognized.

Answer (score 0):

try using html helper beginform()

in index.cshtml

```
   @using (Html.BeginForm("ExportToExcel", "MISReport")) {<div class="uk-form-row">
<label class="uk-form-label" for="R_endDate">Ending Date:</label>
<div class="uk-form-controls">
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.R_endDate, new { @class = "uk-form-small uk-text-left required", @maxlength = 12, @data_uk_datepicker = "{format: 'MM/DD/YYYY'},@name="date" })</div></div>}
```

in the controller

```
      [HttpPost]public FileContentResult ExportToExcel(Datetime date){ .......

}
```